# How can I use fetch with REST API?

Tags: javascript, rest

How can I use fetch method for AJAX with REST API? 
Any example please.

I try to use

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then( (r) => console.log( r ));
```

And did not get JSON as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the promise result in JSON. Try to use

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
   .then( (r)=> r.json() )
   .then( (r) => console.log( r ));
```